# Python: better way to manipulate a list using PyQt5, QCheckbox

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I have a number of checkboxes made using PyQt5. I want to add a string(num) to a list when the box is checked, remove it when it is unchecked. Currently I have this:

```
    def checkbox(self, num, state):
      if state == Qt.Checked:
        if num not in self.checklist:
            self.checklist.append(num)
      elif state != Qt.Checked:
        if num in self.checklist:
            self.checklist.remove(num)
```

it works fine but I was wondering if there's a cleaner way of doing it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a signal called stateChanged which you can use along with a dictionary to implement in O(1)

Comment: I don't think you really need the list. Just read the values directly from the checkboxes. If the checkboxes all have the same parent, you can iterate over them using `parent.findChildren(QCheckBox)`.